# About the turing machine's non-deterministic branches

Tags: complexity-theory

I have three different cases of non-deterministic turing machine.
The first machine has:
Branch "accept" and branch "loop".
The second has:
Branch "rejecte" & branch "loop".
Third has:
Three branchs "rejecte" "loop" "accept".
The question is which machines will  rejecte and which ones will accept and which ones will enter a loop?
Thank you so much

Comment: I cannot understand your question. Perhaps some context is missing.

Comment: It is truly a honor to me that you have taken care of my question. I am a self-taught new student, So for some time I started studying a Non-deterministic Turing machine, Unfortunately, I failed to know when it accepts the or rejects or enters into a loop?<br>
I knew that The machine have a tree and branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, with branches you mean the computation branches (the sequence of the konfigurations M has in its computation) of $M$. Then in general a NTM $M$ will accept an input x, if there exists one computation branch in the computation tree, which leads to accept x, no matter, where other branches may lead to (even if there infinite long). So, Machine 1 and 3 will accept.

I am definitely not sure about the following: I guess, the question, what Machine 2 will do is not decidable (please correct me, if I am wrong)

Comment: very very good i also think that 2 will not stop because it will entre the loop scanning "accept" HOWever i'll check if this right . before a week i saw  a video on NESO ACADEMY about NTM i wish you see it because it very helpful , thank for your answer

Comment: What I said is, that we don't know (more formal: we can't compute), what machine 2 will do. But as already said, I am not completely sure about it.